# MPI_Isend request parameter

Tags: c, mpi

When using `MPI_Isend`, can the `MPI_Request` parameter be a null pointer (when the sender doesn't care about the message after it is sent)?

Comment: Try it? Should give a segfault if it can't.

Comment: Ok, I tried and the answer is no: MPI checks that the request pointer is not null and otherwise prints an error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Short answer is no - the request handle parameter cannot be `NULL`.

`MPI_Isend()` initiates an asynchronous send operation. All asynchronous operations are given a request handle that has to be acted on later in one of the following ways:

- block and wait for the operation to finish with `MPI_Wait()` and friends
- test the operation for completion with `MPI_Test()` and friends until the test turns out positive
- free the handle with `MPI_Request_free()`

Both waiting and testing functions free the request once it has completed. You can also free it immediately after it is returned by `MPI_Isend()`. This will not cancel the operation but rather mark the request for deletion as soon as it is finished. You won't be able to get the status of the send operation though.

If you don't care about the outcome of the asynchronous operation (e.g. completion status, message receive status, error code, etc.), the right thing to do is as follows:

```
MPI_Request req;
...
MPI_Isend(..., &req);
MPI_Request_free(&req);
...
```

Caveat: this works for asynchronous sends since one can devise another method to verify that the send operation has completed, e.g. the destination process might respond after receiving the message. But one should never free an asynchronous receive request and should wait or test for completion instead as there will be no way to know when the operation has been completed.

Comment: This is correct.  I just wanted to add that there is a reason one must complete an `MPI_Request` in some way.  It is possible for an MPI implementation to defer the actual work of sending a message until the `MPI_Wait` (or equivalent) call.  If a request is started and never completed, it is possible that the message will never be sent.

Comment: Thanks! I've expanded the word "result" to better reflect what I did have in mind.